# python scrapy best approach to not re-crawl if already content ID existed

Tags: python, scrapy

below is the crawl results, how do I prevent duplication based on seller_id? At the moment I crawl through pages and pages but want to get unique results based on the ID. If it see the same seller_id within the page from the previous crawl, don't crawl again.

```
{"name": "aaa", "seller_id": "1111", "seller_url": "/s-seller/aaa/1111/date/1"},
{"name": "bbb", "seller_id": "5555", "seller_url": "/s-seller/bbb/5555/date/1"},
{"name": "aaa", "seller_id": "1111", "seller_url": "/s-seller/aaa/1111/date/1"},
```

below is what I have so far, as you can see I do have if int(clean_total_ads) > 500 which filter only ads that is over 500+ and show in the results but I also need to filter unique seller_ID as well

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    for link in sel.xpath("//*[contains(@href, '/aaaad/')]"):
        ad_link = link.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        absolute_url = self.home_url + ad_link
        yield response.follow(absolute_url, self.parse_each_ad)


def parse_each_ad(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first()

    total_ads = remove_tags(extract_with_css('span.seller-profile__number-of-ads'))
    clean_total_ads = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', total_ads)
    name = remove_tags(extract_with_css('span.seller'))
    seller_id_raw = extract_with_css('div.seller a::attr(href)')
    seller_id_compile = re.compile('.*\/(\d+)\/.*')
    seller_id_match = seller_id_compile.match(seller_id_raw).group(1)


    if int(clean_total_ads) > 500:
        yield {
            'name': name,
            'seller_id': seller_id_match,
            'seller_url': seller_id_raw,


             }
```

Comment: Please provide what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy manages duplicate crawling automatically in fact.
If you wish to do it explicitly you can try this:

```
class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'your_spider'
    crawled_ids = set()
...
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    if seller_id not in self.crawled_ids:
        self.crawled_ids.add(seller_id)
        yield request
```

Comment: Is it possible to put the id in a text file for future? Example, if that Id is there again in the future crawl.. Don't crawl again

Comment: Trying to persist set of crawled data will make things more complicated...
I suppose you should open file on spider start, load data to memory, and then write updated data on spider close

Comment: Do you have an example on how I could do this pleae?